# Query error "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having this error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2013-08-01 23:59:59 ORDER BY date' at line 1

With this query

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d ") . "00:00:00";
$end_date =  date("Y-m-d ") . "23:59:59";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM taxi WHERE del IS NULL AND date BETWEEN " . $start_date . " AND " . $end_date . " ORDER BY date");
```

And I have no clue about what it could be as I tried the query in phpMyAdmin and it works fine. Anyone can understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting single quotes around the dates:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM taxi WHERE del IS NULL 
AND date BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '" . $end_date . "' ORDER BY date");
```

Also consider using prepared statements to avoid quotes all together.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: In addition he needs to be checking always for any mysql errors. If he did he would have seen the exact error and troubleshoot himself..